# WebDriver claiming editable element is not editable

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, webdriver

I'm running a simple test with Selenium WebDriver and Python to send/verify receipt of email.

Once I switch to the iframe containing the message body and locate the editable body element and try to clear it out, the following exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@role='textbox']").clear()
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.'
```

Here is the script used to create an email:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("to").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("to").send_keys("toemailaddy@gmail.com")
localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
subj = ("TEST - " + localtime)
print(subj)
driver.find_element_by_name("subjectbox").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("subjectbox").send_keys(subj)
body = ("TEST")
bodyFrame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='Ap']//iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(bodyFrame)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@role='textbox']").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@role='textbox']").send_keys(body)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/div[@role='button' and contains(text(), 'Send')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Inbox (1)").click()
```

However, the message body is explicitly user-editable. Below I've included a snippet of the message body HTML that I have WebDriver directed to within the iframe nested in the td class "Ap" that explicitly shows that it's editable.

```
<body id=":3" class="editable LW-avf" style="min-width: 0px; width: 437px; 
border: 0px none; margin: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
height: 100%; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr; min-height: 121px;" hidefocus="true" 
g_editable="true" role="textbox">
```

IDE is able to access all of the elements, but what could be keeping WebDriver from accessing them?

**EDIT**

Well, I just found out what was causing the exception:

I found that by removing the following line from the script allowed WebDriver to write in the textbox.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@role='textbox']").clear()
```

Though I wonder why it would throw the exception that the element must be editable, but allows it to send_keys to the element without issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with [Action Chains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)?

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.switch_to_frame(bodyFrame)

ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a").perform()
ActionChains(driver).send_keys("Test").perform()

# alternative:
# body_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@role='textbox']")
# body_ele.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
# body_ele.send_keys("Test")
```

In C#, `IWebElement.Clear` says "If this element is a text entry element, the Clear() method will clear the value. It has no effect on other elements. Text entry elements are defined as elements with INPUT or TEXTAREA tags.". Similarly, in [python source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#61), it says "Clears the text if it's a text entry element.", while in your case, `body` is not a text entry element.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, but now having issues with actually hitting "Send" button. If I switch_to_default_content it can't locate it, but there is no discernible iframe or frame that the "Send" button (or overall message) is wrapped in.

I am trying to use the ActionChains send_keys (as well as variations of key_down/key_up) to instead try CTRL+Enter to send the message instead of using the Send button, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Keith: Post the DOM would be helpful (the iframe of the body and the send button), or even better if the site is publicly accessible.

Comment: @Keith: Have you tried `ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER)`?

Answer (score 0):

When i've gotten this error, what I have done is look at the source code page and verify if that element name had been beforehand using a different tag. (i.e. 'label', instead of 'input')
Selenium will always pick the first element that meets its requirements starting from the top of the page.

I would use CSS calls instead of xpath. More precision on what you want called in the body.